# Use of XAML ResourceDictionary outside of EXE to function like CSS file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, customization, resourcedictionary

I have a program wrriten in WPF (C#) where all of the elements has a style that points a static resource located in a ResourceDictionary by the name "Styles.xaml";

Since I need to have the styles customed, I use this file to change colors and fonts to elements all across the program.

The problem is, In order to see the changes I need to recompile, and to have another EXE wich is a slight differ version of the program (differ by colors).
I don't want to maintain many versions of the program.

Is it possible to have a ResourceDictionary (or any other file) outside of the compiled EXE to function as css does with HTML?
Meaning, is it possible to achieve the following: replacing the file in the folder where the EXE lies will be sufficient in order to change the colors?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe you can create a dll with your appropriate ResourceDictionary and then using reflection pull this from the assembly and add them to your Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain a `ResourceDictionary` instance from `.xaml` file (not necessary included in your project) by calling `XamlReader.Load` method and casting the resulting object afterwards. From that point it comes down to manipulating this dictionary in code behind. On application level you can call something like

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dictionary);
```

where dictionary is the instance you have loaded. The same can be done for individual controls.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Nikita Brizhak , I have succeeded.
Here is the full "HOW TO":

1) You need to add an OnStartUp method to App.xaml.cs. Here is the syntax:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
```

2) You have to clear all the resources.

```
  Application.Current.Resources.Clear();//This is if you have on your App.xaml a load of your resource. Clear it and than load another. 
//It is good to have this so you can see you style while working on the project, But on runtime to replace.
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
```

3) you Have to load your dynamic resource

Final Code:

```
 protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        Application.Current.Resources.Clear();
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
        StreamReader stream = new StreamReader("Styles.xaml");
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(stream.BaseStream) as ResourceDictionary);
    }
```